# When using .index in a list only returns first time it appears in the array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
sentence = "ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your country"
sentList = sentence.split()

print(sentence)
userWord = input("Pick a word from the sentence above").lower()

if userWord in sentList:

    while True:
       if sentList.index(userWord) + 1 >= 4:
          print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",sentList.index(userWord) + 1,"th position")
          break

    elif sentList.index(userWord) + 1 == 3:
          print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",sentList.index(userWord) + 1,"rd position")
          break

    elif sentList.index(userWord) + 1 == 2:
        print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",sentList.index(userWord) + 1,"nd position")
        break

    elif sentList.index(userWord) + 1 == 1:
         print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",sentList.index(userWord) + 1,"st position")
         break

else:
     userWord = input("That word isn't in the sentence, try again")
```

When I run the program it only returns the position of the first time it appears in the array.

i.e
    ask not what your country can do for you ask what you can do for your     country

Pick a word from the sentence above: ask

'ask' appears in the sentence in the 1 st position

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Sorry if this is a stupid question I am a coding noobie

Comment: `index()` returns the first occurrence of the `substring`. If you want all the indexes write your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is better.
I left this one as an example of an alternative way.

according to the python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
Index: Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.
```

you should probably use a for loop (the easiest way) or probably it will be a good example of writing a generator.

```
for i,word in enumerate(sentList):
    if userWord == word:
        checkLocation(i,userWord)

def checkLocation(index,userWord):
    if index + 1 >= 4:
        print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",index + 1,"th position")
    elif 
        index + 1 == 3:
        print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",index + 1,"rd position")
    elif 
        index + 1 == 2:
        print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",index + 1,"nd position")
    elif 
        index + 1 == 1:
        print (userWord, "appears in the sentence in the",index + 1,"st position")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) accepts additional start index (and end index). Pass the index to find next matched item index.

```
...

if userWord in sentList:
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            i = sentList.index(userWord, i)  # <---
        except ValueError:  # will raise ValueError unless the item is found
            break
        i += 1
        print("{} appears in the sentence in the {}th position".format(
            userWord, i
        ))

else:
     ....
```

Comment: @Srgrn, It does. Search for the `s.index` in the document I linked in the answer.

Comment: I looked on the tutorial page for lists sorry.